# no. of real solution in exp. equation

Tags: calculus

If $a,b>0$. Then no. of real solution in $\displaystyle (a^x+b^x)^{2013} = (a^{2013}+b^{2013})^x$.

$\underline{\bf{My \; Try}}$:: we can write the equation as $\displaystyle (a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = (a^{2013}+b^{2013})^{\frac{1}{2013}}$

Clearly $x = 2013$ is a one solution of Given equation.

Now we will calculate for other solution whether it is exists or not

So Let $f(x) = (a^x+b^x)^\frac{1}{x}$  and here $(a^{2013}+b^{2013})^{\frac{1}{2013}}$ is a Constant quantity.

Now $\displaystyle f^{'}(x) = (a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot \frac{x.(a^x.\ln a+b^x.\ln b)-(a^x+b^x)}{x^2}$

Now I did not understand how can i find nature of $f(x)$

plz help me how can i proceed furthrt, Thanks

Comment: I would like to know the source of this problem, please.

Comment: I have seen few days ago in Aops.

Comment: Maybe you could add a link, so we don't duplicate effort.

Comment: Yes Sir I am seraching for that perticular post. Thanks